# Identify this Harvestman

Tags: zoology, species-identification, arachnology

I spotted this guy in Switzerland. It's clearly an [*Opilione*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opiliones) (*Harvestman*), but I really know nearly enough about this diverse group to be able to identify the species.

[image: Unidentified Opilione]

Sorry, I didn't think to place any reference near it for scale. Can anyone tell me the species or at least the genus? (Bonus points if anyone can guess what it's feeding on)

Comment: you smashed the poor guy?

Comment: @DevashishDas No of course not; I didn't harm either one. I saw him, took the photo, then moved on.

Comment: Sorry, i was just kidding. Anyway, is this is the one? http://www.fcps.edu/islandcreekes/ecology/Arthropods/Harvestman/harvestman.jpg

Comment: It could be. The coloration is similar. Can you find another image that more shows back a bit more clearly and cite the species?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is probably **Daddy Longlegs (*Leiobunum vittatum*)**

[image]

this invert color image show the resemblance.

[image]

Source: 
http://www.insectidentification.org/insect-description.asp?identification=Eastern-Harvestman

http://bugguide.net/node/view/840130

---

Might be eating a cockroach:

[image]

### UPDATE:

### OR

It might be *Mitopus morio*(modern harvestman)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm a little skeptical of this identification though. First, in my image, there is a dark stripe down the back behind the eyes, but in yours, the body appears almost entirely dark with light fringes on the side and light joints. Second, several sources claim the distribution of *Leiobunum vittatum* is limited to North America, but my specimen was from Switzerland. I'll leave the question open for now, but I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I think you are right. But I am pretty sure genus is correct. Look for a species which have two parallel sets of dots on the back in that genus.

Comment: Age and sex may be a factor for body color.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it's a *Mitopus morio*. The coloration and patterning is correct, as well as the distribution.